# Clang 13, 14, and 15 compiling for release causing incorrect incrementing of variables

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, runtime-error, llvm

I'm writing a simple little wavefront object (.obj) file loading utility. Code and .obj file required to recreate this issue are found here [on this github repository](https://github.com/oliver-peoples/clang-wtf)

The first step I use is to count the number of vertices, vertex normals, vertex texture locations, and parameters. This is done by incrementing a counter:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

#define glMat2X Eigen::Matrix<float,2,Eigen::Dynamic>
#define glMat3X Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic>
#define glMat4X Eigen::Matrix<float,4,Eigen::Dynamic>
#define glArr3I Eigen::Array<int,3,Eigen::Dynamic>

struct Mesh
{
    glMat4X vertices;
    glMat3X vertex_normals;
    glMat2X vertex_textures;
    glMat3X parameters;
    glArr3I facets;
};

void loadWavefrontObj(
    std::string path,
    Mesh& mesh
)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");

    char line_buffer[512];

    int _vertices = 0;
    int _vertex_normals = 0;
    int _vertex_textures = 0;
    int _parameters = 0;
    int _facets = 0;

    while (!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(
            &line_buffer[0],
            512,
            f
        );

        char type[3];

        sscanf(line_buffer, "%s ", &type[0]);

        std::string type_str = type;

        // printf("%s: %s, %i\n", type_str.c_str(), line_buffer, type_str == "vt");

        if ( type_str == "v" )
        {
            _vertices++;

            // printf("vertex: %s\n", type);
        }

        if ( type_str == "vn" )
        {
            _vertex_normals++;
            // printf("vertex normal: %s, %i\n", type_str.c_str(), vertex_normals);
        }

        if ( type_str == "f" )
        {
            _facets++;
        }

        if ( type_str == "vt" )
        {
            _vertex_textures++;
            printf("vertex texture: %s, %i\n", type, _vertex_textures);
        }
    }

    printf("vertex_normals: %i\n", _vertex_normals);
    printf("vertex_textures: %i\n", _vertex_textures);
    mesh.vertices = glMat4X::Ones(4,_vertices);
    mesh.vertex_normals = glMat3X::Ones(3, _vertex_normals);
    mesh.vertex_textures = glMat2X::Ones(2, _vertex_textures);
    mesh.facets = glArr3I::Ones(3, _facets);
}

int main()
{
    Mesh mesh;

    loadWavefrontObj(
        "icosphere.obj",
        mesh
    );

    printf("mesh.vertices.cols(): %li\n", mesh.vertices.cols());
    printf("mesh.vertex_normals.cols(): %li\n", mesh.vertex_normals.cols());
    printf("mesh.vertex_textures.cols(): %li\n", mesh.vertex_textures.cols());
    printf("mesh.facets.cols(): %li\n", mesh.facets.cols());
    // printf("%li\n", mesh.vertices.cols());

    // printf("%i,%i,%i,%i\n", mesh->facets_present, mesh->vertex_normals_present, mesh->parameters_present, mesh->vertices_present);

    return 0;
}
```

When running for release, the outputs from Clang 14 & 15 are:

```
vertex_normals: 7107693
vertex_textures: 10593
mesh.vertices.cols(): 10242
mesh.vertex_normals.cols(): 7107693
mesh.vertex_textures.cols(): 10593
mesh.facets.cols(): 20481
```

and for Clang 13:

```
vertex_normals: 20480
vertex_textures: 7107693
mesh.vertices.cols(): 10242
mesh.vertex_normals.cols(): 20480
mesh.vertex_textures.cols(): 7107693
mesh.facets.cols(): 20481
```

The correct outputs (as produced with every GCC version and Clang <= 12 are:

```
vertex_normals: 20480
vertex_textures: 10593
mesh.vertices.cols(): 10242
mesh.vertex_normals.cols(): 20480
mesh.vertex_textures.cols(): 10593
mesh.facets.cols(): 20481
```

I can fix this simply with:

```
int volatile _vertices = 0;
int volatile _vertex_normals = 0;
int volatile _vertex_textures = 0;
int volatile _parameters = 0;
int volatile _facets = 0;
```

However I've never had to do this before. What *on earth* is going on?

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) is a good place to start. You should also be checking the return value from `sscanf` to be sure it isn't failing. The trailing space in the format string is probably not desired either.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sure. !eof(file) is not the optimal way to do *file reading*, however that's not what I'm here for, and it's not a good place to start. If that was the issue, then incrementing the counters would likely be a problem for all counters; however it isn't. I will rewrite with the method you've linked, however, I do not think it will make difference; kudos to you if it does.

Comment: The problem is, unless we have 3 versions of clang and want to download a large file from your repository, we can't test it and it isn't clear what steps you took to debug it. Sure there's commented out printf statements in the code but we don't know what they told you. I'm more concerned with `sscanf` failing or the measly 3 character buffer overflowing and overwriting other data on the stack, like the counters.

Comment: Since this is marginally a c++ program I'd use `std::getline` to read the line and a `std::stringstream` to grab the type, and when you get there the rest of the data. Much safer.

Comment: @RetiredNinja my apologies; your answer worked! Can you add a answer so I can flag it as correct?

Comment: Try compiling your program with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` and see what happens when you run it

Comment: I'm not certain which of my random shots in the dark helped, but happy something did. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja it was using getline; I've pushed the change to github.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255978/discussion-between-balluwun-enjoyer-and-retired-ninja).